# Strange Windows Phone ListBoxItem Layout

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListBox` in my XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxDataTemplate}" 
BorderThickness="0" />
```

`ListBoxDataTemplate` is

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="34" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" 
Grid.Column="0">A QUICK BROWN</TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,0,4,0" 
Width="30" Height="30" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Dark/icon.arrowright.png" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But when I run this on emulator, instead of the the `Image` align to right in row,
the `Image` position is right after `Text` `A QUICK BROWN`.

Here screenshot from emulator,

[image: ListBoxItem]

XAML code is here : http://pastebin.com/GVqC2Si9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your grid column for the image is only 34
change it to

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I would also add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to the image xaml

**EDIT**

tried your code and notice you had to add HorizontalContentAlignment

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxDataTemplate}" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I try your solution but still same, btw I put grid outside DataTemplate, and the layout is what I expected.

Comment: yes, it would help to show the full xaml. My suggestions would still hold true

Comment: I try your code in simplest layout page, the result is same.
You can check here: http://pastebin.com/XZx3FZy7